# Javascript external didn't work but when inline work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a fullscreen image modal in web, when i place the script in html, the modal is work finely. but when i move the script into external js, it didn't work. i've examined all variable carefully  and i think all correct. i think the problem is in function to show the modal. but i didn't find the solution. sorry, I am beginner in javascript, help me.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementById("image01");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.image {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.image:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) !important;
}


/* Modal Content (Image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 500px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="mb-3 row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="p-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/500" class="img-fluid image" id="image01" alt="Example">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Open up the developer tools then load it. Do you see any errors? One quick way to open developer tools is right click anywhere on the page, select inspect then click the console tab.

Answer (score 1):

if this is your whole html code, you may call external js file like this :

```
<script src="yourjs.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your js code in `custom.js` file
and import js file at the end of the html code.

```html
.
.
.
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="mb-3 row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="p-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/500" class="img-fluid image" id="image01" alt="Example">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

.
.
.
<script src="custom.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: I have done it. but the modal didnt appear

Comment: Js file is present at right path?
Is there any status 404 for the file in network tab of browser?

Comment: The code is working for me. Make sure your js file present at correct path.